# Trouble installing quantstrat package on MAC

Tags: r, install.packages, quantstrat

I'm sure it's a dumb question but I am currently doing the quantitative analyst course in R on datacamp and I cannot install and require the quantstrat package: please view the code and error I get below:

`remotes::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")`

Downloading GitHub repo braverock/quantstrat@master
Skipping 1 packages not available: blotter
✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/vj/hns236zs3td7hn6xlrq60g840000gn/T/Rtmprb7rht/remotes13e7359179ac/braverock-quantstrat-9960e3e/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘quantstrat’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  looking to see if a ‘data/datalist’ file should be added
     NB: this package now depends on R (>= 3.5.0)
     WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects:  'quantstrat/data/luxor.wfa.ples.RData'  WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects: 'quantstrat/luxor.wfa.ples.RData'
─  building 'quantstrat_0.16.6.tar.gz'

Then I get this message below after it attempts to download it:

ERROR: dependency ‘blotter’ is not available for package ‘quantstrat’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/quantstrat’
Error: Failed to install 'quantstrat' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/vj/hns236zs3td7hn6xlrq60g840000gn/T//Rtmprb7rht/file13e7487dac5f/quantstrat_0.16.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

Seemed blotter wasn't installed. If someone is experiencing the same issue:

```
remotes::install_github("braverock/blotter")
remotes::install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```

This should work :)